# Minimum transfer Sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two Tables and I need to fulfill table 2 `Need_qty` with minimum movement from table 1 `sending_qty`.

Table 1

```
sending_QTY STORE_ID_A
30           30105
16           21168
10           21032
9            30118
6            30011
5            21190
2            21016
```

Table 2

```
Need_QTY    STORE_ID_B
15           21005
10           30019
11           21006
16           30001
11           21015
7            21004
```

Expected output

```
STORE_ID_A |STORE_ID_B |TRANSFERRED_QTY_FROM_A |
-----------|-----------|-----------------------|
30105      |21005      |15                     |
30105      |30019      |10                     |
30105      |21006      |5                      |
21168      |21006      |6                      |
21168      |30001      |10                     |
21032      |30001      |6                      |
21032      |21015      |4                      |
30118      |21015      |7                      |
30118      |21004      |2                      |
30011      |21004      |5                      |
```

There are several other combinations to achieve this but I need to find minimum possible transfer so that table 2 need_qty gets fullfill
Is there any way to achieve this without procedural approach?

So far I have tried to cross join to find the combinations but didn't help much

Comment: when you say "fulfill", you mean to insert items from table 1 into table 2 that do not already exist in table 2?

Comment: @krokodilko One the interval overlap solution I tried but is there anyway to minimize the movement

Comment: None of the store ids in the first table exist in the second table, or is this just not good sample data?I can't figure out if there is any relationship at all between the two tables. How do you come up with those numbers?

Comment: exactly. therefore we're not sure if the task is understood correctly. maybe you could add some lines with expected outcome first? are you talking about some kind of gaps-and-islands algorithm?

Comment: @JNevill  I have added sample output data

Comment: @dlatikay  I have added some sample data

Comment: Oh! I see. Start with `30105` from the `table 1` and start subtracting values from  `table 2` (sorted by qty desc) until you hit 0. The remainder from the last record in `table 2` is left. Repeat with the next value from `table 1` starting with that remainder, if there is one.

Comment: nice puzzle! is there a real-world problem behind? and no business logic layer in sight that would handle this better?

Comment: How do you define "minimum movement"? Other than that, this sounds like a typical "packing problem" - there are several algorithms for solving. Don't expect "the optimal" solution in general (that would require unreasonable amount of processing time), but just "reasonably good" solutions. There have been some good discussions on OTN regarding these problems in the past few months.

Comment: I would echo @mathguy -- If minimum movement means the smallest number of transfers to meet all `need_qty`, there are solutions that take less than the 10 steps in the example data.  One jumps out to me that takes 7 steps to fill all `need_qty`.  There are probably others that take fewer than that.  Is the goal to fill the `need_qty` in the smallest number of transfers?

Comment: @alexgibbs exactly smallest number of transfers to meet all need_qty

Comment: @mathguy my aim is to the minimum number of transfers. Is it possible to write this in sql ?

Comment: @dlatikay This is a real world problem of the supply chain .This is one of the part of the requirement

Comment: What is a "transfer"? In any given solution, what is the "number of transfers"? That is something I still don't understand.

Comment: @mathguy in the given problem number rows = number of transfers to meet all need_qty . for given example its 10 . but as dlatikay pointed by doing 7 transfers also we can meet all need_qty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using regular SQL by utilizing an assisting table, containing partitions of integers. For the sake of this example, let's assume this assisting table has three columns: partitions, rank and number. For any given number, there will be rows of possible partitions, each with its rank. If the number is 5, selecting all the rows from this table where number is 5 will bring up:

```
partitions          rank        number
5                   1           5
4, 1                2           5
3, 2                2           5
3, 1, 1             3           5
2, 2, 1             3           5
2, 1, 1, 1          4           5
1, 1, 1, 1, 1       5           5
```

The rank is the number of partitions used in the row, and it's important for the problem you provided because it allows us to select the minimum transfers.

For the number 5 we have 7 rows representing partitions. For higher numbers the rows returned will be much higher - the number 12 will have 77 partitions! - but in the scale we work in with databases, this assisting table of partitions is easy to query in numbers 1 through 99, such as the example provided. Higher numbers are a question of scalability.

If you want instructions to create such a table, I'll be happy to provide you - but since this is a long solution, let's set the generation of the assisting table aside for now.

Let's look at Store ID A, which had quantity to send. Their quantities are:

```
30
16
10
9
6
5
2
```

For each store quantity we can query the partitions assisting table, and get the various partitions for this quantity and their rank. We can then create out own combination of partitions. For instance, 30 will bring many rows, one of which will be:

```
partitions         rank         number
15,10,5            3            30
```

and 10 will bring in, among many others:

```
partitions         rank         number
6,4                2            10
```

You could build a Cartesian product of all possible candidates by a cross join between the results, and for each row of this product have the partitions ordered in ascending order and the rank be the sum of the partition ranks.

On the other side, you have Store ID B which needs quantities. You just do the same exact treatment, ending up with yet another quite large Cartesian product of ranked, ordered partitions. Congratulations on getting so far.

Now, you only need to see the partition rows in which Store ID B partition collection is completely contained within Store ID A partition collection. This will thin the large collection considerably to a few rows of potential transfers. One of the rows from Store ID B (given the example above) will be:

```
partitions                     rank
15,10,10,7,6,6,5,5,4,2         10
```

Since it appears in both Store ID A and Store ID B. in Store ID A it will be a combination of:

```
30 = 15,10,5     rank 3
16 = 10,6        rank 2
10 = 6,4         rank 2
9  = 7,2         rank 2
6  = 5,1         rank 2
5  = 5           rank 1
2  = 2           rank 1
```

giving you the line:

```
partitions                     rank
15,10,10,7,6,6,5,5,5,4,2,2,1   13
```

The last step is to select the row with the lowest rank on the Store ID B. This will be the minimal number of transfers, and you can output it just like you did above.

BONUS for getting this far: If you want to see if We can completely deplete Store ID A's entire inventory (rather then fulfil Store ID B), reverse the containment relation: Make sure the partition collection A is completely contained in partition collection B. To see the minimal transfers for moving exactly each item from A to B fulfilling B and depleting A, look for identical partitions in both collections.

And some actual SQL to simulate the algorithm, at least in part:

```
-- this function handles the sorting. It's not necessary but it help make the result look better.
WITH
FUNCTION SORT_PARTITIONS(p_id IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
result VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN   
  select rtrim(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,str||',')).EXTRACT('//text()'),',') into result  
from (
with temp as  (
   select p_id num from dual       
 )
SELECT   trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) str
FROM (SELECT num str FROM temp) t
CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
order by to_number(str)
);
return result;
END;
-- this function handles containment - when we want to fulfil store ID B, and not necessarily deplete store ID A, or visa-versa.
FUNCTION PARTITION_CONTAINED(seta_partition IN VARCHAR2, setb_partition IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
result NUMBER;
BEGIN
 with seta as 
(select str, count(str) cnt from (
SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) str
FROM (SELECT num str FROM (select SETA_PARTITION num from dual)) t
CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0)
group by str),
setb as 
(select str, count(str) cnt from (
SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) str
FROM (SELECT num str FROM (select SETB_PARTITION num from dual)) t
CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0)
group by str),
lenab as (select count(1) strab from seta, setb where seta.str=setb.str and seta.cnt>=setb.cnt),
lenb as (select count(1) strb from setb)
select strb-strab into result from lenb,lenab;
RETURN result;
END;
-- this store_a simply represents a small Cartesian product of two stores from the stores ID A table - one with quantity 5, the other with quantity 4. I found this was easier to set up. 
store_a as (select SORT_PARTITIONS(n1||','||n2) partitions_sending, rank1+rank2 rank_sending from (select num_partitions n1, rank rank1 from n_partitions where num=5),(select num_partitions n2, rank rank2 from n_partitions where num=4)),

-- this store_b represents the stores ID B's Cartesian product of partitions, again for simplicity. The receiving quantities are 3, 3 and 3.
store_b as (select SORT_PARTITIONS(n1||','||n2||','||n3) partitions_receive, rank1+rank2+rank3 rank_receive from (select num_partitions n1, rank rank1 from n_partitions where num=3),(select num_partitions n2, rank rank2 from n_partitions where num=3),(select num_partitions n3, rank rank3 from n_partitions where num=3))

-- and finally, the filtering that provides all possible transfers - with both "=" (which works for deplete and fulfil) and "partition_contained" which allows for fulfil or deplete. You can choose to leave both or just use partition contained, as it is more flexible.
SELECT * from store_a, store_b where store_a.partitions_sending=store_b.partitions_receive or partition_contained(store_a.partitions_sending,store_b.partitions_receive)=0 order by store_b.rank_receive, store_a.rank_sending asc;
```

Comment: Thank you so much giving direction looks interesting algorithm. Can you give query to build assisting table

Comment: The example below will provide all 3-rank partitions for the number 12. You can run this with various parameters to generate rows in the table with various number and rank. To change the number just change the top line. To change rank you will need to add n_range tables accordingly and add to the where.
with nth_w as (select 12 nth from dual),
n_range as (select rownum t from dual, nth_w connect by rownum <= nth_w.nth)
select distinct
r1.t||','||r2.t||','||r3.t breakdown, 3
from 
n_range r1,n_range r2, n_range r3, nth_w
where 
r1.t>=r2.t and r2.t>=r3.t 
and r1.t+r2.t+r3.t = nth_w.nth;

Comment: Thanks you so much .Seems like I am struggling to understand the logic middle and final part. If you can edit your answer and put some SQL query to achieve the final result with help of assisting table it will be great.

Comment: That will take some time - creating the assisting table, populating it, creating the store tables with sample data - I will try to find time tomorrow to set up the environment. I'm glad you liked the solution.

Comment: Thanks! I will also try to write it . This innovative algorithm has any name?

Comment: I just call it minimal partition matching. I'll edit my efforts today in the original answer.

Comment: Great, I'm happy to hear!